# How to return the value of a variable only when a button has been clicked?

Tags: python, tkinter

My code:

```
def file_exists(f_name):
        select = 0

        def skip():
            nonlocal select
            select = 1
            err_msg.destroy()

        def overwrite():
            nonlocal select
            select = 2
            err_msg.destroy()

        def rename():
            global select
            select = 3
            err_msg.destroy()

        # Determine whether already existing zip member's name is a file or a folder

        if f_name[-1] == "/":
            target = "folder"
        else:
            target = "file"

        # Display a warning message if a file or folder already exists

        ''' Create a custom message box with three buttons: skip, overwrite and rename. Depending
            on the users change the value of the variable 'select' and close the child window'''

        if select != 0:
            return select
```

I know using nonlocal is evil but I have to go on with my procedural approach, at least for this program.

The problem is when I call this function it rushes through and returns the initial value of `select` (which is 0) immediately, no matter which button I've pressed. When I press a button, the value of `select` will change accordingly.

So how can I return it only after a button has been pressed? As you can see, my first attempt was to return the value only when select is `!= 0` but this doesn't work.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Did I understand this correctly, you want the `file_exists` function to block until the user presses a button and then return the updated `select` value?

Comment: I want to block returning the value until a user pressed one of three buttons. Did you edit my posting? If so, thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're calling the `file_exists` function early? If the function needs to wait for something to happen, that basically means you've called it too early, doesn't it? Instead of waiting for the button click to happen, you should connect a function to the button so that it gets executed when the button is pressed. It's a lot easier to call the function at the right time than to call it early and wait for something to happen. Basically like `Button(callback=do_stuff_with_select)`.

Comment: Well, creating a warning message with three buttons is part of this function., so it's a nested function. For the sake of clarity I didn't post the code. Instead I just inserted a commend explaining what I intend to do. Actually the order is like that: 1. recognize double file names 2. create a custom message box with three buttons 3. react to the users choice 4. return an appropriate value

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. You just need put all the code that you want to run after the `return select` in a function and call that function when one of the three buttons is pressed.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: BTW: the connected functions are already there. If the user press a button, the functions def skip() or def overwrite() or def rename() are executed. But since they are bound to buttons, they cannot return a value directly.

Comment: @Grendel do you actually know how to call a function by clicking a button?

Comment: Hi Parviz Karimli, I did it this way:     skip_button = Button(button_frame, text="Skip", width=11, command=skip)
            skip_button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ew")

Comment: I mean, it actually works. It's only that the function immediately returns a value while my custom message box is displayed. Even when there's no button clicked so far.

Comment: @Rawing: do I have access to the values inside a function from an outer scope? I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the [`.update()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) function to block without freezing the GUI. Basically you call `root.update()` in a loop until a condition is fulfilled. An example:

```
def block():
    import Tkinter as tk

    w= tk.Tk()

    var= tk.IntVar()
    def c1():
        var.set(1)
    b1= tk.Button(w, text='1', command=c1)
    b1.grid()

    def c2():
        var.set(2)
    b2= tk.Button(w, text='2', command=c2)
    b2.grid()

    while var.get()==0:
        w.update()
    w.destroy()

    return var.get()

print(block())
```

Comment: Hi Rawing, yes your suggestion seems to work! Thanks to you and to all other guys here!

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `update` in a loop. Instead, you can ask tkinter to block until a variable changes values (eg: w.wait_variable(var)`)

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately there's no tkinter variable to be changed.